# Probability of two friends being in the same group when the group size is not same

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 10 people are divided into 2 groups of 6 and 4. What's the probability that two friends A and B are in the same group?

Comment: What is the probability of say A be in group 1 (6 people)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the probability that they are both in the 4-people group? What is the probability that they are both in the 6-people group?

Now what is the probability that one of these two events happens?

Comment: The 2 friends could be in one of the 2 groups in 2! ways. There are $$ \binom{10}{4} = 210 \textrm{ groups} $$ ways of assigning the people into 2 groups. With that the probability of the two being in the same group is $$ \binom{8}{2}/\binom{10}{4} \textrm {}$$

Comment: I am not sure if my thinking is right! I might be, but looking for a more concrete explanation to reinforce my concept.

Comment: @SamV  If both friends are in the six person group, then four of the other eight people must be in their group.  If both friends are in the four person group, then two of the other eight people must be in their group.